# How do I plot a system with gain, first-order lag and time delay?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the output response of a system with gain, first-order lag and time delay, where the transfer function is

```
tf = 2 Exp[-0.1 s]/(.1 + s)
```

To plot a time delay, we need to use an approximation, as *Mathematica*'s `TransferFunctionModel` is restricted to rational transfer functions. We can use a Padé approximation

```
pa = PadeApproximant[tf, {s, 0, 5}]
```

and then determine the output response and plot it using

```
model = TransferFunctionModel[pa, s]
output = OutputResponse[model, UnitStep[t], t];
Plot[output, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

My output response looks very weird:

[image: time delay plot]

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: most likely the function is complex in that interval

Comment: b.t.w welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `Chop` to your output:

```
output = OutputResponse[model, UnitStep[t], t] // Chop
Plot[output, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

you will get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is quite different. `Chop` removes small (in your case imaginary) roundoff errors.
At this stage though I would try and make sure the result actually makes sense. These roundoff errors are slightly suspicious.
One test you can do is ask for higher precision in the computation, via say

```
pa = PadeApproximant[tf, {s, 0, 5}]//N[#,20]&
```

which in this context seems to produce the same solution.

Comment: I was thinking the gap might have something to do with an imaginary component, but I tried using `Re[]`, which didn't help that much. Thanks for introducing me to `Chop`!

Comment: If I were you I would do a few tests to make sure the answer is correct though. The fact that you need to use `Chop` is an indication that your result might not be very robust.