# Please explain this unexpected code snippet behavior

Tags: complex

Consider a function that maps a complex function z->f(z) to it's multivariable counterpart (x,y)->f(x,y)

```
complex2multivar[z_] := ComplexExpand[Through[{Re, Im}[z]]]
```

Here are some results:

As expected:

```
complex2multivar[2 #^2 &[x + I y]]
{2 x^2 - 2 y^2, 4 x y}
```

As expected:

```
t1[z_] := 2 z^2
complex2multivar[t1[x + I y]]
{2 x^2 - 2 y^2, 4 x y}
```

NOT as expected:

```
t2[z_] := 2. z^2
complex2multivar[t2[x + I y]]
{(0. + 0. I) + 2. x^2 - 2. y^2, (0. + 0. I) + 4. x y}
```

Please explain this unexpected behavior.

How can this be fixed such that I can use pure functions like

```
(a # + b) / (c # + d) &
```

where the a,b,c,d are of type

```
Real + Real I
```

for example

```
a = 1.4 + .7 I
```

Comment: Yes, it was the inexact numbers that did it. Use `Chop[]`.

Comment: That is a new one for me.

Comment: And it works too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [(13679)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13679/121),
[(24783)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24783/121),
[(57377)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57377/121) (and many more...)

Comment: @Guess Can you help me find and select a good original to mark this question as a duplicate of?

Comment: Duplicate of which question @Guesswhoitis.?

Comment: See the link below the title.